# Error lines seaborn factorplot not appearing

Tags: python-3.x, graph, seaborn

Q1) How can I add the error lines? std_weight column has the same dimensions as the other columns.

Q2) How can I move the legend so its horizontal and at the top of the graph?

My error lines dont want to appear.

This is a snippit of the csv file:

```
line,testcase,algorithm,group,avg_weightedcost,std_weight
yrh,1,ALG3,0,20007037.36,0
yrh,1,AEA,0,30007016.46,3.76E-09
yrh,1,ALG2,0,181801581.2,13353630.74
yrh,1,ALG1,0,585605657.3,54852458.59
yrh,1,ALG4,0,30007016.46,0
yrh,1,ALG3,1,20007037.36,0
```

This is the code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df1.head()

def plot(x, y, data=None, label=None, **kwargs):
sns.pointplot(x, y, data=data, label=label, **kwargs)

g = sns.factorplot(y="algorithm", x="avg_weightedcost",  
               hue="group", col="testcase",row="line", 
               data=df1, kind="bar",
               size=5, aspect=.9)

plt.grid(True, which="both")

for ax in g.axes.flat:  
    ax.grid(True, which="both")
```

This is what I get:
[image]

This is how I tried adding the error lines - using 'xerr':

```
g = sns.factorplot(y="algorithm", x="avg_weightedcost",  xerr="std_weight",
               hue="group", col="testcase",row="line", 
               data=df1, kind="bar",
               size=5, aspect=.9)
```

This is the error i get:

```
 ValueError: err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]
```

Comment: Seaborn usually calculates the error by itself. Here your data does not allow to calculate any error, as it seems to be one datum per bar. There might be ways to achieve the desired output using a FacetGrid, or creating the bar plots with matplotlib directly. However for further help it would be useful to have a [mcve] available.

Comment: I did end up using facet grid, it does calculate the errors by itself. I wanted some way of plotting precalculated averages and standard deviations.  What do you think is the most suitable way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Personally, I often prefer to use matplotlib directly. This will result in more code lines but makes everything that's happening more transparent.